# How can I tell how much heap memory I have at any given moment?

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I have a process that keeps dying in the same place, and claims to be running out of memory, but I have a sneaking suspicion that it's a red herring and that I'm eating up the memory it needs somewhere else.  I'm curious what my options are for seeing memory used and released in real time.  Does ADB have a monitor of some kind that I can watch?

TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find the command line **adb shell dumpsys meminfo 'your apps package name'** useful. If you want see the info for all processes, use **adb shell dumpsys meminfo**. It's probably worth piping the output to a text file, as there's a lot of data of the form:

```
** MEMINFO in pid 5527 [com.sec.android.widgetapp.weatherclock] **
                    native   dalvik    other    total
            size:     2868     5767      N/A     8635
       allocated:     2861     2891      N/A     5752
            free:        6     2876      N/A     2882
           (Pss):      532       80     2479     3091
  (shared dirty):      932     2004     6060     8996
    (priv dirty):      512       36     1872     2420

 Objects
           Views:        0        ViewRoots:        0
     AppContexts:        0       Activities:        0
          Assets:        3    AssetManagers:        3
   Local Binders:        2    Proxy Binders:        8
Death Recipients:        0
 OpenSSL Sockets:        0


 SQL
               heap:        0         MEMORY_USED:        0
 PAGECACHE_OVERFLOW:        0         MALLOC_SIZE:        0
```

that comes back from a real device connected via the USB port

Comment: is this how DDMS on eclipse shows the heap size memory (used vs total) ? if so, on which of the cells here does it look at?

Answer (score 1):

I use the DDMS perspective in Eclipse, which has a "Heap" tab for this kind of monitoring. I'm not sure if there are command line alternatives for consumption by other IDE's.